# Convert vector of enum values into an another vector

Tags: serialization, iterator, rust

I have the following code which generates a vector of bytes from the passed vector of enum values:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum BertType {
    SmallInteger(u8),
    Integer(i32),
    Float(f64),
    String(String),
    Boolean(bool),
    Tuple(BertTuple),
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct BertTuple {
    pub values: Vec<BertType>
}

pub struct Serializer;

pub trait Serialize<T> {
    fn to_bert(&self, data: T) -> Vec<u8>;
}

impl Serializer {
    fn enum_value_to_binary(&self, enum_value: BertType) -> Vec<u8> {
        match enum_value {
            BertType::SmallInteger(value_u8) => self.to_bert(value_u8),
            BertType::Integer(value_i32) => self.to_bert(value_i32),
            BertType::Float(value_f64) => self.to_bert(value_f64),
            BertType::String(string) => self.to_bert(string),
            BertType::Boolean(boolean) => self.to_bert(boolean),
            BertType::Tuple(tuple) => self.to_bert(tuple),
        }
    }
}

// some functions for serialize bool/integer/etc. into Vec<u8>
// ...

impl Serialize<BertTuple> for Serializer {
    fn to_bert(&self, data: BertTuple) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut binary: Vec<u8> = data.values
            .iter()
            .map(|&item| self.enum_value_to_binary(item)) // <-- what the issue there?
            .collect();

        let arity = data.values.len();
        match arity {
            0...255 => self.get_small_tuple(arity as u8, binary),
            _ => self.get_large_tuple(arity as i32, binary),
        }
    }
}
```

But when compiling, I receive an error with iterating around `map`:

```
error: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not satisfied [E0277]
           .collect();
           ^~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u8>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
error: aborting due to previous error
error: Could not compile `bert-rs`.
```

How can I fix this issue with `std::iter::FromIterator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `enum_value_to_binary` returns a `Vec<u8>` for each element in `values`. So you end up with an `Iterator<Item=Vec<u8>>` and you call `collect::<Vec<u8>>()` on that, but it doesn't know how to flatten the nested vectors. If you want all the values to be flattened into one `Vec<u8>`, then you should use `flat_map` instead of `map`:

```
let mut binary: Vec<u8> = data.values
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|item| self.enum_value_to_binary(item).into_iter()) 
            .collect();
```

Or, slightly more idiomatic and performant, you can just have `enum_value_to_binary` return an iterator directly.

Also, the `iter` method returns an `Iterator<Item=&'a T>`, which means you are just borrowing the elements, but `self.enum_value_to_binary` wants to take ownership over the value. There's a couple of ways to fix that. One option would be to use `into_iter` instead of `iter`, which will give you the elements by value. If you do that, you'll move the `arity` variable up to before the `binary` variable, since creating the `binary` variable will take ownership (move) `data.values`.

The other option would be to change `self.enum_value_to_binary` to take it's argument by reference.

Also possible that you meant for the type of `binary` to actually be `Vec<Vec<u8>>`.

Comment: No, in my example I want to return a vector of bytes. 
Compiler has generate `cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]`  error for the `|&item|` expression.